# Struts2 Web application 404 error

Tags: java, eclipse, struts2, http-status-code-404

I am using

- Eclipse 4.5.2
- Apache Tomcat 7.0.34
- Struts 2.5

When I run the project in Eclipse I get a 404 error.

**404 Error:**

[image]

Codes in my project are as below:

**web.xml**

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app>
  <display-name>Struts 2 Web Application</display-name>

  <filter>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher</filter-class>
  </filter>
<!-- 
   <filter>
        <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>encoding</param-name>
            <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
 -->
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>

<welcome-file-list>
  <welcome-file>welcome</welcome-file>
  <welcome-file>login</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

**login.jsp**

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>
<html>
<head>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Struts 2 localization example</h1>

<s:form action="validateUser" namespace="/user">

<s:textfield key="global.username" name="username" />
<s:password key="global.password" name="password"/> 
<s:submit key="global.submit" name="submit" />

</s:form>

<s:url var="localeEN" namespace="/" action="locale" >
   <s:param name="request_locale" >en</s:param>
</s:url>
<s:url var="localezhCN" namespace="/" action="locale" >
   <s:param name="request_locale" >zh_CN</s:param>
</s:url>
<s:url var="localeDE" namespace="/" action="locale" >
   <s:param name="request_locale" >de</s:param>
</s:url>
<s:url var="localeFR" namespace="/" action="locale" >
   <s:param name="request_locale" >fr</s:param>
</s:url>

<s:a href="%{localeEN}" >English</s:a>
<s:a href="%{localezhCN}" >Chinese</s:a>
<s:a href="%{localeDE}" >German</s:a>
<s:a href="%{localeFR}" >France</s:a>

</body>
</html>
```

**welcome.jsp**

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>
<html>

<body>
<h1>Struts 2 localization example</h1>

<h4>
<s:property value="username"/>
</h4>

</body>
</html>
```

**struts.xml**

```
<constant name="struts.custom.i18n.resources" value="global" />
<constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />

<package name="user" namespace="/user" extends="struts-default">
    <action name="login">
        <result>pages/login.jsp</result>
    </action>
    <action name="validateUser" class="com.mkyong.user.action.LoginAction">
        <result name="SUCCESS">pages/welcome.jsp</result>
        <result name="input">pages/login.jsp</result>
    </action>
</package>

<package name="default" namespace="/" extends="struts-default">
    <action name="locale" class="com.mkyong.common.action.LocaleAction">
        <result name="SUCCESS">user/pages/login.jsp</result>
    </action>
</package>


<package name="emptyaction" namespace="/" extends="default">
<default-action-ref name="" />
<action name="">
    <result type="redirect">/</result>
</action>
</package>
```

**Structure**
My project structure is:

[image]

Comment: What is the struts version?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that. I'm using Struts 2.5.

Comment: At this point, I would want to see the actual contents of the WAR file deployed to Tomcat.  I'm not sure how you would find that.

Comment: @AliZakeri Have you solved this problem? i have encountered the same issue.Posts on StackOverFlow are not helping me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Struts 2.5 the `FilterDispatcher` is deprecated. It's deprecated since Struts 2.1.3 and shouldn't be used in newer versions.

> As from Struts 2.5 all filters were moved to dedicated package, see
>   the example:
>
> ```xml
> <web-app id="WebApp_9" version="2.4"
>     xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
>     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
>     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
>
>     <filter>
>         <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
>         <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
>     ...
> ```

The `resource not available` error comes from Tomcat, because it's unable to find a resource for the root folder such as welcome file `index.jsp`.

The `welcome-file-list` could be used in your `web.xml`

```xml
<welcome-file-list>
  <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

---

If you don't want to use `welcome-file-list` then you should map "default" action (with empty name) to the package with root (`"/"`) namespace.

**For example**

```xml
<package name="root" namespace="/" extends="struts-default">

  <!-- root -->

  <action name="">
    <result>/user/pages/welcome.jsp</result>
  </action>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I have included "welcome-file-list" in my web.xml file (see update web.xml), however, the problem still persists.

Comment: Did you update `struts.xml` to include empty action in the root package? Without finding action config in the root namespace struts is unable  to serve your acition which is not mapped with the request url provided. Also try to reinstall tomcat from the fresh clean installation package.

Comment: I have updated the code in my struts.xml, but still get the error.

Comment: "The requested resource is not available"

Comment: The context /Struts2Example didn't start. You didn't apply updates from this answer.

Comment: Can you please tell me which update? I have updated both struts.xml and web.xml as shown above.

Comment: Where did you do that? It's not from this answer because if you do that the filter should start.

Comment: I applied the updates you mentioned: **1)** I have used welcome-file-list at the end of my web.xml and **2)** I defined empty action at the very end of my struts.xml. Is there anything I'm missing?

Comment: Any suggestions at this stage?

Comment: Did you change a class name of the `struts2` filter?

Comment: No I haven't changed class name of the filter.

Comment: So you haven't changed it that why it doesn't work. Do you need more suggestions or more answers?

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that's because you haven't told it what to render.  There is no content in the root directory of the web context, and you haven't specified a welcome file in the web.xml.

It might be useful to try adding "/user/pages/welcome.jsp" (a page that you haven't shown us) to your browser URL and see if it renders the "welcome.jsp" page.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I am not very familiar with Eclipse. Can you please explain how I can add  "/user/pages/welcome.jsp"  to my browser URL? Thanks.

Comment: Your issues have nothing to do with Eclipse, except for the fact that you're apparently testing your app using the embedded browser in Eclipse.  I'm just saying to change the URL in that browser, changing "http://localhost:8080/Struts2Example/" to "http://localhost:8080/Struts2Example/user/pages/welcome.jsp". If it renders the content of the "welcome.jsp" page, then that tells you your app is correctly deployed, you just haven't configured the welcome file properly.

Comment: @DavidM.Karr Struts2 is used to browse actions, that have ".action" extension or without it, don't access jsp pages directly.